# What happened to Nausicaa at the end of the movie?

Tags: nausicaa-of-the-valley-of-the-wind

In the final act of *Nausicaa of the Valley of the Wind*,

> the titular character gets trampled by the Ohmu stampede and lies motionless. The Ohmu then stop their attack, pick her body up, and do *something* which wakes her up again.

I seem to remember Miyazaki stating that he disliked that people found Messianic overtones in the movie.

> Did Nausicaa die, and get resurrected by the Ohmu? Or was she simply badly hurt and the Ohum healed her?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking, there is no way to know, as the creators have not said one way or another. However, we're led to believe the following (excerpt from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nausica%C3%A4_of_the_Valley_of_the_Wind_%28film%29#Plot)):

> The herd, however, calms down, and the Ohmus use their golden tentacles to heal Nausicaä's wounded body.

Based on the use of the words "heal" and "wounded", it seems she never *actually* died.

Additionally, there is this bit from [the Nausicaä Wiki](http://nausicaa.wikia.com/wiki/Nausicaa_Of_The_Valley_Of_The_Wind_Wiki):

> Nausicaä was badly injured trying to save her people from an attack by the Omhus. She stood before the rush of angry creatures, almost costing her her life. The Omhus, however, revived Nausicaä and she was brought back to conciousness.

Unfortunately, it's not cited to any specific source, but it seems to be the general concensus.

Comment: The two are essentially equivalent, especially in a work like this that has no "after-life" dimension to the plot.

Answer (score 0):

The original Miyazaki movie has the short sequence of the final scenes where Nausicaa is seen back in her home town, living happy life and teaching younger children.

Hence obviously she was not killed, just wounded, and later recovered.